# Controller error: Invalid controller: name='dasdada'

Tags: controller

I am trying to send information from a  to a DB.

I am using Jfactory. This is the HTML:

```
<textarea name="task" class="form-control" id="task"></textarea>
```

Variable:

```
$_POST['task']
```

This is the HTML that injects:

```
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
 $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__reports'))
       ->columns(array('client', 'site', 'percent', 'tarea', 'time', 'assignto'))
       ->values(implode(',', array($db->quote($client), $db->quote($site), $db->quote($percent), $db->quote($task), $db->quote($getDate), $db->quote($userAssign)) ));
 $db->setQuery($query);
 $result = $db->query();
```

The weird thing is that everytime I put a "." (point) I got this error:

===>  Invalid controller: name='dasdada', format=''

The MySQL field is on TEXT and I have tried LONGTEXT and Varchar

Comment: It's nothing to do with the query you've shown us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of textarea name, don't use 'task' which is in use for controller routing requests, try "mytask" or whatever, and update references elsewhere in the code